# Eight queens in java

Tags: java, n-queens

Here is my code for the eight queens problem. I checked it with many test case and it's correct. But when I submitted it to https://open.kattis.com/, it noticed me that my code is the wrong answer. So, where is my code fails? Please help!

```
public class Chesss {
  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] row = new int[8];
    int[] column = new int[8];
    int[] lcros= new int[15];
    int[] rcros = new int[15];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
      row[i] = 0;
      column[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i ++) {
      lcros[i] = 0;
      rcros[i] = 0;
    }
    boolean check = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j ++) {
        char in = (char)System.in.read();
        if (in == '\n') {
          in = (char)System.in.read();
        }
        if (in == '*') {
          if (row[i] == 1) {
            check = false;
          } else {
            row[i] = 1;
          }
          if (column[j] == 1) {
            check = false;
          } else {
            column[j] = 1;
          }
          if (lcros[i + j] == 1) {
            check = false;
          } else {
            lcros[i + j] = 1;
          }
          if (rcros[i - j + 7] == 1) {
            check = false;
          } else {
            rcros[i - j + 7] = 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (check == true) {
      System.out.print("valid");
    } else System.out.print("invalid");
  }
}
```

Comment: could you help us help you by giving meaningful names for your variables instead of a,b,c,d...? you know, it might even help you see the errors...

Comment: and what is the input that you are getting? why do you need any input to solve the 8 queens problem ????

Comment: @sharonbn The program accepts a solution and validates it.

Comment: This is **not** how this site works. We will not lookup that problem to figure what the input/outputs should be; and then figure what your program is doing wrong. You figure that yourself; and give that information; and then we might help with finding the root cause!

Comment: Oh, I submited my code to a website that have test cases to test my code,

Comment: are you sure you are required only to validate a solution? if the website does not give you adequate information why your code is rejected, no one will do this for you.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, that's right

Comment: @sharonbn if the error is compiling error, ít will give me why my code is rejected, but wrong answer is not

Comment: @trueterry, that is not what springs to mind when one reads "Here is my code for eight queens problem"

Comment: What is row, what is column, what is lcros, what is rcros, what is the inputs? Does an input of * mean there's a queen? Leave commenting on what you are trying to do on each if statement

Comment: input is '*' is queen and '.' is space in chess board

Comment: How does your lcross and rcross work? I get row and column are used to store if an queen is in that row or column, but why is lcross and rcross 15 in length?

Comment: For starters, you do not check if there really are eight queens on the board.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we know that your code is meant to "validate a solution to 8 queens problem", there are several problems with your code. here are the glaring most obvious two :

1. You have to get the positions of **ALL** 8 queens **BEFORE** you start the validation process
2. You have to check all the straight lines in all directions from the queens' positions, stopping at the edge of the chess board

I dont see all this in your code

Comment: Have another look at the solution, its idea is to iteratively mark columns, rows and left or right diagonals as "blocked" and when it gets the position of a new queen it verifies that the position is not "blocked" and then updates the "blocked" fields.